# Run a kotlin flow once but have it received twice downstream

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

## Scenario

I have a hot flow `EventHandler.sharedFlow` emitted on a button click.

The flow is received by `Repository` that performs some action in `OnEach{}`.

The repository flow is then received by two event collectors `EventCollectorA` and `EventCollectorB`.

The event collector flows are then combined and collected in `MyViewModel`.

## Issue

The two event collectors cause `onEach{...}` to run twice on every click. However I only want to run `onEach{...}` once and have it received in two event collectors. How can I achieve this?

Note: I am using Hilt to ony have one instance of `Repository`, `EventCollectorA` and `EventCollectorB`

[image: Flow Diagram]

## Code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        binding.buttonB.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.userClickEvent("Click Event")
        }
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val eventHandler: EventHandler,
    private val eventCollectorA: EventCollectorA,
    private val eventCollectorB: EventCollectorB,
) : ViewModel() {
    fun userClickEvent(event: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
        eventHandler.userClick(event)
    }

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            combine(
                eventCollectorA.sharedFlow,
                eventCollectorB.sharedFlow
            ) { a, b ->
                {/*do something*/}
            }.collect()
        }
    }
}
```

```
class EventHandler  {
    private val _sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
    val sharedFlow = _sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()

    suspend fun userClick(event: String) {
        _sharedFlow.emit(event)
    }
}
```

```
class Repository constructor(
    eventHandler: EventHandler,
) {
    val sharedFlow = eventHandler.sharedFlow
            .filter { it == "Click Event" }
            .onEach {/*do something*/} /*onEach is called twice on click event. I only want it called once*/ 
            .onStart { emit("Begin") }
}
```

```
class EventCollectorA constructor(repository: Repository) {
    val sharedFlow = repository.sharedFlow.map {
        it
    }
}

class EventCollectorB constructor(repository: Repository) {
    val sharedFlow = repository.sharedFlow.map {
        it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that while `eventHandler.sharedFlow` is a `SharedFlow`, after applying any operators to it, we get a regular, not shared flow. `filter()`, `onEach()` and `onStart()` are running separately for each new collection. If you want to share them between collections, you need to construct another shared flow, after applying them:

```kotlin
    val sharedFlow = eventHandler.sharedFlow
            .filter { it == "Click Event" }
            .onEach {/*do something*/}
            .onStart { emit("Begin") }
            .shareIn(...)
```

**Further explanation**

We need to be aware that a regular, cold flow is not like a live stream of data. It is more like a source of such streams and with each new collection we start entirely new stream of data. For example, if we create a flow using `flow { }` builder, we have only a single flow object, but if we invoke `collect {}` multiple times on it, then for each collection the lambda will be invoked again and again. Similarly, each operator that we use to construct a new flow, is also invoked separately for each collection.

You can think of `shareIn()` as creating a service that observes its upstream flow and duplicates its data to each of its downstream flows. No matter how many times we collect the shared flow, upstream flow will be collected only once. Operators above `shareIn()` will be invoked once, while operators below `shareIn()` will be invoked separately for each collection.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented `shareIn()` with `GlobalScope` and appears to be working as intended. I still do not fully understand how `shareIn()` solves the issue. Is it converging all downstream subscribers into one channel which which everything is emitted into? Any layman's term explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: @mairs8 See my updated answer.